# Most important buildings in 3 player version

Tags: machi-koro

In Machi Koro (base game), finding an optimal strategy depends on the number of players involved, since you take turns rolling the dice. Green and purple buildings are only activated when you roll the dice, red buildings only by your opponents and blue by every player.

In a two player game, most of the strategies I've come up with hinge on using green buildings. In a four player game, blue and red are dominant. But what about 3 players? Is there an optimal strategy, or are all options considered equal?

I guess I'm looking for a list of buildings with the highest expected return rate in a 3 player game (unless you think expected return is not the primary metric for choosing your buildings).

Comment: thinking about it, the question is too broad, it would take too much time to answer because it would tend to "create a machi koro guide"

Comment: I think the expected return rate has too many unknowns.  The return rate on reds depends on whether other players have money when they roll that number.  You also have to take into account the potential of building stealing, synergies such as the shopping mall, roll diversity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question in part because I think it will depend on what your opponents have. Blue buildings trigger on every roll, but don't tend to generate as much income as the green buildings. If your opponents have a lot of red buildings, I'd guess it would be more helpful to have green buildings so that you can earn a lot in one go (and red buildings trigger first). Blue buildings can have income trickle in more regularly, but the income will trickle out for your rolls that trigger red buildings and for their rolls that trigger purple buildings.

Red buildings will probably still be useful, though not as useful as in 4 player games.

I have not played a lot of three player games of Machi Koro, but I would guess that it provides the best balance between the power of the differently colored buildings.

Answer (score -1):

As usual, I think it depends on what your opponent have.
Some guidelines I usually follow:

- Most of the players are still rolling with one dice? Then try to buy the Sushi Bar: it is cheap and you receive a lot of income if your opponents roll a 1.
- Is there a Mine available and you can purchase it? Do it. The number 9 is likely to be rolled with a huge amount of chances.
- Are your opponents builidng a lot of red buildings? Build the IRS if available.

Comment: 2 of the three buildings you mention are expansion buildings, which the question doesn't seem to be including.